# Shops selling wine/alcohol at Manila airport T1 and T4

Tags: airports, shopping, philippines, duty-free, manila

Are there any wine shops at Manila airport T1 or T4?

I'll be landing on Terminal 1 around 12h00 and departing from terminal 4 around 18h00 and I would love to buy some wine in between, preferably in Terminal 4. Both flights will be domestic.

Is this possible?

Bonus, if someone could confirm the availability of porto wine at the airport I would really appreciate.

Comment: You cannot buy duty-free on domestic flights.

Comment: @dda I know, I meant duty free in the sense that they for sure always sell alcohol/wines. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Duty-free has only one meaning: products that are sold in bonded areas, and not subject to taxes. Shops in domestic terminals are not duty-free.

Answer (score 3):

There are, at least the outside ones, that are open until 21PM as far as I remember, do not know about the internal ones to the airports. For those outside, you have to get outside and catch a taxi. You can only enter on such shops showing your travel airplane tickets. However, those duty free stores are only for international flights, I am afraid.

As you are mentioning domestic flights, as inside the Phillipines, the prices are much cheaper outside in supermarkets than in the shops inside the terminals. They are all (mostly) upscale/luxury stores, and prices are more expensive on the shops inside the domestic terminals, to the tune of 3 times more expensive, at least for local goods for selling to tourists.

Thus, I would advise buying the bottle in a supermarket and not in the airport.

If you are worried about breaking it in your backpack, and we are talking about Port wine, you have got them in plain bottles, or bottles inside carton cases, metal and wood cases.

While you have got an added cost with the case,  it still will be cheaper than buying it in the airport.  It makes it more presentable as a gift too. (a wood case might also give you less problems with the x-rays in the airport than a metal case).

PS. I did not find the prices cheap in general in Philippines even in the international tax free shops. I did much more better deals in Istambul.

Comment: My objective is to buy a bottle of wine and take it with me on the plane. This means, buy it after security on T4. Otherwise I'll need to find some space for it on my luggage and hope it will not break during handling.

Comment: I advise you buying it and putting it inside a plastic bag in the middle of the clothes. Done it many times. You will have a far better choice of brands/products for a much cheaper price outside the airport. I as a tourist, shied away from the domestic airport stores in PH, prices are quite inflated. If you are not confy with carrying it in the luggage, Oporto bottles also come with their external carton/metal package, and the price is only slightly higher for that.

Comment: Sadly I'm not living in Portugal neither departing from Portugal. I'll be traveling with a 50L backpack. Because it is not a hard case luggage I'm kinda afraid of bad handling and breaking it up. I'll have 7 flights before I get to the place where I will present the bottle :/

Comment: If we are talking about Port wine, you have got them in plain bottles, or bottles inside carton cases, metal and wood cases. While you have got an added cost with the case, you are more prone to find what you want *outside* the airport, and on top of that, it still might be cheaper even if you find it inside. Get it with a wood or metal case for a good measure. It makes it more presentable as a gift too. (a wood case might also give you less problems with the x-rays in the airport than a metal case)

Comment: If you have so many flights, at which point will they also request of you to put the bottle inside the luggage?